# How to get the id of and html element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following structure:

```
<input name="20735" class="form-control valid-dateonly error" id="20735" required="" type="text" maxlength="4000" placeholder="" value="">
<label class="error" style="left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; position: absolute;" for="20735">This field is required.</label>
<span class="input-group-addon">            
    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
</span>
<div id="div_20735"></div>
```

Basically, I have  the label control in `JQuery $this`. Now basically I want to capture the div with `id:div_20735`. If you observe, this `20735` is the `id` of the input control also, which is placed above the label.
I am guessing something like `$(this).prev().id`...but am not getting.But I am getting this value(20735), when I do `$(this).prev().context.htmlfor`..but I dont think thats the best way to retrieve.
This is what I have tried:

```
 $('label.error').not('.hide').each(function () {

    var previousElm = $(this).prev();
    if ($(previousElm).hasClass("form-control")) {

        $("#div_20735").after($(this));//here I need help to capture the id of the div dynamically

        $(this).css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'white-space': 'nowrap', 'left':'0px' });
    }           

});
```

Any help to find the best way will be highly appretiated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this - It takes the `for` attribute value which is what you need

```
$('label.error').not('.hide').each(function () {

    var previousElm = $(this).prev();
    if ($(previousElm).hasClass("form-control")) {

      var divID = $(this).attr('for');

      $("#div_" + divID).after($(this));//here I need help to capture the id of the div dynamically

      $(this).css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'white-space': 'nowrap', 'left':'0px' });
    }           

});
```

Comment: Thanks Darren!Thats working fine in IE. Eventhough I was more inclined towards getting the ID from the input field before and not the attribute of the label itself, but I believe it should work in all scenario since the label itself is tied with that input field which is required field.   But I will test and confirm for wider audience.

Answer (score 0):

This `$("#div_" + previousElm.attr('name'))` should do the trick:

```
$('label.error').not('.hide').each(function () {

    var previousElm = $(this).prev();
    if ($(previousElm).hasClass("form-control")) {

        $("#div_" + previousElm.attr('name')).after($(this));//here I need help to capture the id of the div dynamically

        $(this).css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'white-space': 'nowrap', 'left':'0px' });
    }           

});
```